# Bash is skipping read command

Tags: bash

`vformat` is not taking any value. Can anyone help me with this?

**sample youtube video:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqOeMYtOc1w

**Code:**

```
# Color
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
BLUE='\[\033[0;34m\]'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

function red {
    printf "${RED}$@${NC}\n"
}

function green {
    printf "${GREEN}$@${NC}\n"
}

function yellow {
    printf "${YELLOW}$@${NC}\n"
}

function blue {
    printf "${BLUE}$@${NC}\n"
}

# echo $(red apple) $(yellow banana)

echo $(red "Enter url:")
read url

# echo "$url"
url="https:${url##*https:}"
# url=$(echo "$url" | egrep -o 'https?://[^ ")]+')

allFormat=$(youtube-dl -F "$url")
echo "$allFormat"

echo $(blue "\nEnter format to download video:")
read vformat

echo $(green "Enter directory to download:")
read -r dpath

echo $(green "Enter start time to skip the video in s:")
read stime

title=$(youtube-dl --get-title "$url")
# echo "$title"

mod_title=$(echo "$title" | tr ' ' '_' | tr ':' '@')

echo $vformat

l=$(youtube-dl -f "${vformat:-18}" --verbose --newline -o "$dpath/$mod_title/$title.mp4" "$url" | grep --line-buffered -oP '^\[download\].*?\K([0-9.]+\%|#\d+ of \d)' |
    zenity --progress \
    --width=400 \
  --title="Downloading youtube video" \
  --text="Downloading..." \
  --percentage=0)
echo "$l"
```

[image]

Comment: `echo $(red` just `red "stuff"`, no echo. `allFormat is not taking any value. Can anyone help me with this?` What do you mean? It looks from the output it is taking a value. What do you mean exactly? Try running `bash -x ./your_script.sh` and see what happens. Do you mean `vformat` is not taking any value? Are you pressing enter too many times? Just press one enter, and wait. The script works nicely for me, nice zenity progress bar.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Still skipping it :( it's taking blank value once I get the format list. it gets automatically skipped vformat I meant

Comment: Sorry yes I meant `vformat`

Comment: It looks like youtube-dl -F is outputting to stderr, hence why you still see the output on the console. Consider redirecting the output with 2>&1.

Comment: Yes It's the main culprit. ```allFormat=$(youtube-dl -F "$url")
echo "$allFormat"
``` How to fix it? I am new to bash

Comment: got it.` \[\]` this was provided by that `allFormat`. How do I remove it from display? ```echo "$allFormat" 1>&2 ```

Comment: also when I enter url if there is enter than it get passed to vformat how do I stop this?

Comment: `[] this was provided by that allFormat` No, it's in blue. You have `BLUE='\[\033[0;34m\]'` So the `[]` stay. `when I enter url if there is enter than it get passed to vformat how do I stop this?` You must be typing too fast. Just type type, press enter, and wait. To me it looks you are pressing enter twice. There is a blank link after the url, before `[youtube]`. It's an empty enter. Maybe, you are copying the text, and in the text copy in clipboard there already is an enter included. Then don't press it.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Thanks you for giving your time helping me :). Got it made changes and I need to be patient while entering the input.

Comment: You should always post text for session logs or messaging.  **Never** images, unless they specifically show a graphic condition which is not captured by the plain text.  I ended up using an OCR program to convert the image, because, for some reason, my version (2020.03.24) of **youtube-dl** is always giving me "unable to download", even though my browser plugin works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra "**[]**" have been removed from the definition of "BLUE".  That was the source of unexpected brackets.

I've added **command line options** to allow batch programming.

I've added **conditionals** for cases where some parameters are not known (*i.e. actual video formats available*).

I've coded in a "**--test**" case to prove out the logic without actually downloading.  That also generates additional *progress reporting of values* captured along the way.

Also note, the code for prefixing "naked" urls with the "**https://**", instead of only "**http:**"

The code segment for "**stime**" was commented out because it wasn't being used for download.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Color
    NC='\033[0m' # No Color
   RED='\033[0;31m'
 GREEN='\033[0;32m'
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
  BLUE='\033[0;34m'

function red {
    printf "${RED}$@${NC}\n"
}

function green {
    printf "${GREEN}$@${NC}\n"
}

function yellow {
    printf "${YELLOW}$@${NC}\n"
}

function blue {
    printf "${BLUE}$@${NC}\n"
}

doTest=0
doit=0
DBG=0

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --test )    doTest=1    ; DBG=1 ; shift ;;
        --force )   doit=1      ; shift ;;
        --url )     url="$2"    ; shift ; shift ;;
        --dir )     dpath="${2}"    ; shift ; shift ;;
        --skip )    stime="${2}"    ; shift ; shift ;;
        --vformat ) vformat="${2}"  ; shift ; shift ;;
        * ) echo "\n Invalid parameter on command line.  Only allowed: [ --force ]\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ; ;;
    esac
done

# echo $(red apple) $(yellow banana)

if [ -z "${url}" ]
then
    echo -e $(yellow "\n Enter url => ") "\c"
    read url
fi

testor=$(echo "${url}" | grep '^http://' )
if [ -z "${testor}" ]
then
    echo "fence"
    #url=$(echo "$url" | egrep -o 'https?://[^ ")]+')
    #url="https:${url##*https:}"
    url="https://${url##*https:\/\/}"
fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e " url= ${url}" >&2

rm -f yt.log yt.err
if [ ${doTest} -eq 1 ]
then
    cat >yt.log <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
[youtube] TqOeMytOc1w: Downloading webpage
EnDoFiNpUt

    cat >yt.err <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
[info] Available formats for TqOemytociw:
format code extension resolution note
249 webn    audio only tiny  48k    , webm_dash container, opus @ 48k (48000Hz), 2.34MiB
250 webn    audio only tiny  71k    , webm_dash container, opus @ 71k (48000Hz), 3.44MiB
251 webn    audio only tiny 124k    , webm_dash container, opus @124k (48000Hz), 5.93MiB
140 naa audio only tiny 127k    , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@127k (44100Hz), 6.08MiB
278 webn    256x144    144p  17k    , webm_dash container, vp9@ 17k, 15fps, video only, 856.01KiB
160 mp4 256x144    144p  21k    , mp4_dash container, avc1.42c00c@ 21k, 15fps, video only, 1.04MiB
242 webn    426x240    240p  26k    , webm_dash container, vp9@ 26k, 30fps, video only, 1.27MiB
133 mp4 426x240    240p  44k    , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d4015@ 44k, 30fps, video only, 2.14MiB
134 mp4 640x360    360p  23k    , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d401e@ 23k, 30fps, video only, 1.12MiB
243 webn    640x360    360p  46k    , webm_dash container, vp9@ 46k, 30fps, video only, 2.20MiB
135 mp4 854x480    480p  34k    , mp4_dash container, avc1.4d401f@ 34k, 30fps, video only, 1.65MiB
244 webn    854x480    480p  6Sk    , webm_dash container, vp9@ 65k, 30fps, video only, 3.14MiB
18  mp4 640x360    360p 149k    , avc1.42001E, 30fps, mp4a.40.2 (44100Hz) (best)
EnDoFiNpUt

else
    test ${DBG} -eq 1 && set -x 
    youtube-dl -F "${url}" >yt.log 2>yt.err
    test ${DBG} -eq 1 && set +x 
fi

allFormat=$(cat yt.err | grep -v '^ERROR:')

if [ -z "${allFormat}" ]
then
    echo -e "\t allFormat= "
    awk '{ printf("\t\t %s| %s\n", FILENAME, $0 ) ; }' yt.log yt.err >&2
    echo -e "\t No formats could be identified.  Unable to proceed.\n Bye!!\n" >&2 ; exit 1
fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 &&  echo "${allFormat}" | awk '{ printf("   %s\n", $0 ) ; }' >&2

if [ -z "${vformat}" ]
then
    echo -e $(blue "\n Enter format (from first column) to download video => ") "\c"
    read vformat

    if [ -z "${vformat}" ]
    then
        echo -e "\t No video format selected.  Unable to proceed.\n Bye!!\n" >&2 ; exit 1
    fi

    row=`eval grep \'^${vformat}\' yt.err `
    if [ -z "${row}" ]
    then
        echo -e "\t Invalid entry for video format.  Unable to proceed.\n Bye!!\n" >&2 ; exit 1
    fi
    test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e " row= ${row}" >&2
fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e " vformat= ${vformat}" >&2

dpath=""

if [ -n "${dpath}" ]
then
    if [ ! -d "${dpath}" ]
    then
        echo -e "\t Directory '${dpath}' not found.  Unable to proceed.\n Bye!!\n" >&2 ; exit 1
    fi
fi

if [ -z "${dpath}" ]
then
    echo -e $(green "\n Enter directory to download => ") "\c"
    read -r dpath
    if [ -z "${dpath}" ]
    then
        echo -e "\t No directory path entered.  Unable to proceed.\n Bye!!\n" >&2 ; exit 1
    fi
fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e " dpath= ${dpath}" >&2

### There is no skip time option for youtube-dl Version 2020.03.24
### The 'stime' variable is not used for the actual download command execution
###
#if [ -z "${stime}" ]
#then
#   echo -e $(green "\n Enter start time to skip the video in s => ") "\c"
#   read stime
#   if [ -z "${stime}" ]
#   then
#       echo -e "\t No skip time entered.  Using default '0'."
#   fi
#fi
#test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\t stime= ${stime}" >&2

title=$(youtube-dl --get-title "${url}")
if [ -z "${title}" ]
then
    echo -e "\t No title could be identified.  Unable to proceed.\n Bye!!\n" >&2 ; exit 1
fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e " title= ${title}" >&2

mod_title=$(echo "${title}" | tr ' ' '_' | tr ':' '@')
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e " mod_title= ${mod_title}" >&2

if [ ${doit} -eq 0 ] ; then  exit ; fi

l=$(youtube-dl -f "${vformat:-18}" --verbose --newline -o "${dpath}/${mod_title}/${title}.mp4" "${url}" | grep --line-buffered -oP '^\[download\].*?\K([0-9.]+\%|#\d+ of \d)' |
    zenity \
    --progress \
    --width=400 \
    --title="Downloading youtube video" \
    --text="Downloading..." \
    --percentage=0
)
echo "${l}"
```